How can I make each column in a Table display according to its custom width setting
I'm using PowerApps.
How can I make each column in a Table display according to its custom width setting, instead of using the automatic column width? I've noticed that the automatic width often doesn't fully display the column content.
I've tried setting the width in the right-hand properties pane, but it seems like it's setting the width of the entire table, not the individual columns within the table.
